# Xamarin Forms with Windows phone - MediaElement not working

Tags: c#, audio, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

I created Windows Phone 8.1 app with Xamarin Forms. I used MediaElement in MainPage.xaml and I use wav file(path Assets/ring.wav) It is my code:

```
<forms:WindowsPhonePage 
 ....>

<Grid>
    <MediaElement Name="PlayElement"
                  MediaOpened="PlayElement_OnMediaOpened"
                  MediaFailed="PlayElement_OnMediaFailed"
                  AutoPlay="False"/>
</Grid>
```

It is code behind :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   PlayElement.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/ring.wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
```

I use DependencyService in Xamarin, but I have not sound. I have not exception - my code worked  - and I have silence. My event PlayElement_OnMediaOpened - not working.
 I create test project for Windows Phone 8.1 and it is work. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please share some codes of your dependency service Implementation?

Comment: My dependence service is work. I see my break point. Event MediaOpened  on WP - is not fire.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/241026#Comment_241026). The author advises to use MediaPlayer(in background). I decided to use toast notification. MediaElement is not working for me.